# Undefined reference to an assembly function

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly, cross-compiling

An assembly function is to be called from a c++ program

My simple **assembly code** is (1.s)

```
.align 4
.code 32           
.globl testfunc 
.func 
 testfunc:
          bx lr
         .endfunc
 .end
```

**C++ code is** (1.cpp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C"
{
    void testfunc(void);
}

int main()
{
   testfunc();
   printf("completed\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled assembly code using **arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as -o 1.o 1.s**

When C++ code is compiled with **arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o 1c.o 1.cpp**  getting an error that

**In function main, undefined reference to testfunc()**

Why is this happening even i declared testfunc() as extern ?

Comment: You have to declare it as `extern "C"` to get the name mangling right.

Comment: I used the following
extern "C"
{
void testfunc(void);
}
Still showing the same error

Comment: Hm...  maybe there's some other name mangling going on? Some compilers add an underscore to C function names. It might be most instructive to write a small C program and look at the generated machine code.

Comment: I always write a bit of C code and "copy" the compiler's code when writing assembler files... E.g. arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -S 1.cpp -o 1c.s

Comment: Try to compile with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c 1.cpp

Comment: In the compilers code there was just **bl _testfunc** and there is no mention of it that the function is external

I even copied the compiler code and modified it but still the problem persists

Comment: @Maciej that works :) and whats the difference

Comment: Not the void one -c flag

Comment: Kerrek: the leading underscore is an a.out/coff function that is sometimes (but rarely) perpetuated on other targets if an OS goes through an arch change.   But arm-gnueabi is not one of those, ELF and no underscore.

Comment: @Maciej `(void)` does not mean take one argument in C++!!! `(void)` is supported in C++ for C compatibility, and it means the same thing as `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compilation argument list is in that form:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o 1c.o 1.cpp
```

It means do something with 1.cpp to get object file as an output. I'm not sure what it is going to do but in your case it could go with linking too.
When it is in that form

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c 1.cpp
```

It means explicity to do only compilation step on file 1.cpp. Without linking and resolving dependecies

If there are problems with linking
After that use

```
objdump -T
```

on both .o files and check if the name of the function is same. There could be some problems with underscores some compilators add them some not
Check if your function is compiled with underscore and if not add it manually in assembly code